# Why POST use Webrequest always fail but use html form is success?

Tags: c#, system.net.httpwebrequest

I spent two days to debug but I can't find error's cause.
App client using WebRequest call servlet result is fail, WebException is "The operation has time out" but When I call servlet by POST method in html form is success. Here is code C#:

```
public string PostURLRequest(string URL, string postData)
{
    try
    {
        System.Text.Encoding enc =
            System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis");

        byte[] postDataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        System.Net.HttpWebRequest req =
            (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);
        req.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ReadWriteTimeout = -1;
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
        req.Timeout = 10*60*1000;

        System.IO.Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();

        reqStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
        reqStream.Close();

        System.Net.WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();//----------> THROW EXCEPTION HERE
        System.IO.Stream resStream = res.GetResponseStream();

        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resStream, enc);
        String text = sr.ReadToEnd();

        sr.Close();
        return text;
    }
    catch(System.Net.WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Status == System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return "NG";
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend proxying both requests through a tool like Fiddler, and examining how they are different. It would also be useful for us to see an example of `postData`.

Comment: I've seen a similar problem before when automating actions to websites or Web APIs.  It was often caused by the request not containing all of the header data that the recipient was expecting to receive (example, the correct user agent, cookies, incorrect keep-alive setting).  Try to verify that your request is faithfully sending the same header data that you are in your browser

Comment: @John, thank you, I will try it

Comment: @MartinParkin, I will continue debug with your idea, thank you.